# ReferenceError: mesagge is not defined

Tags: bots, discord

Help!, im creating a bot for discord and i put it a prefix, so the error comes when i want to use a command how "(a.richembed)" in discord in the terminal of VSC I get the error "ReferenceError: mesagge is not defined" and i dont know how to fix it, please help me!, heres my code

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
let prefix = "a."

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log("Ready to give Atis");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.content.startsWith("ATIS JTPH")) {
    message.channel.send("Information for airport: JTPH--------- Information: Zulu--------- Time: ..........  (eg 16:45:00z)--------- Active Runways: 09L, 09R, 27L, 27R--------- WInd: .....@...   (eg 360@15)--------- Clouds:Clear--------- Visibility: >20KM--------- Remarks:None--------- Tower Frequency: 121.20--------- Ground Frequency: 121.30--------- Delivert Center: 121.40--------- Center Frequency: 121.50---------  Emergency Frequency 121.60.");
  }
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+ "Help!")){
  message.channel.send("Sending the emergency services to you!")
}
if(mesagge.channel.send.startsWith(prefix,"richembed")){
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle("What i can do?")
    .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor(0x00AE86)
    .setDescription("Well, mainly I'm designed by my creator Carlos and he coded me to be able to give information to the pilots who need it.")
    .setFooter("They will ask: Why is that bot there and why does it have those roles? well, very simple, if you say ATIS JTPH I will tell you a few things about the defined airport such as JTPH!", client.user.avatarURL)
    .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setURL("https://github.com/CraterMaik")
    .addField("These texts are still configured by my creator, please be patient!.", true)
    .addField("These texts are still configured by my creator, please be patient!",  true)
    .addBlankField(true)
    .addField("These texts are still configured by my creator, please be patient!.", true);
    
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
});
client.login("NjM1MTk5NzE1NTUzODM3MDg2.XbO1Sw.mappUgFXIYeqj5_FgYFQ30TBDto")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a typo you typed mesagge instead of message